# Build error - PIP installer for Petrel

Tags: pip, installation, ocean, petrel

I am trying to create a PIP installer for a Petrel plugin, but i'm getting an error. At first plugin version and at first build, it works. When I try to update the plugin version and create a new installer, I get the following error:

> ERROR: Folder
>   C:\Users\Fernanda\Desktop\PetrelPluginSEA\EconomicAnalysis\bin\Debug\
>   overlaps with a previously registered folder

The command that generates this error is the following:

> C:\Users\Fernanda>"%OCEAN2015HOME%\PluginPackager.exe" /p
>   "C:\Users\Fernanda\Desktop\PetrelPluginSEA\Installer\obj\copytemp\EconomicAnalysis.dll"
>   "C:\Users\Fernanda\Desktop\PetrelPluginSEA\Installer\bin\Debug\Installer.pip"
>   "%OCEAN2015HOME%\petrel.exe" -helpfile 
>   "C:\Users\Fernanda\Desktop\PetrelPluginSEA\Installer\HelpFiles\example_CL.chm"
>   "C:\Users\Fernanda\Desktop\PetrelPluginSEA\Installer\HelpFiles\example.chm"
>   ERROR: Folder
>   C:\Users\Fernanda\Desktop\PetrelPluginSEA\EconomicAnalysis\bin\Debug\
>   overlaps with a previously registered folder

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Because you changed the version the previous installation that was done by the previous build is not cleaned out. When you rebuild with the new version it finds the previous installation registered in your PluginManagerSettings.xml file. Do the following:

1. Use Build > Clean Solution in Visual Studio
2. Open the folder where the plug-in assembly is created when you build and delete it if it is there.
3. Open your PluginManagerSettings.xml file and remove the  lines that define your plug-in.
4. Rebuild your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `PluginManagerSettings.xml` file to edit is located in the users' `%appdata%` storage location.

With Petrel 2022 it is located here: `%appdata%\Schlumberger\Petrel\2022\PluginManagerSettings.xml`